# Guava ClassPath.from(MyClass.class.getClassLoader()).getTopLevelClassesRecursive("mypackage") returns 0 elements

Tags: java, guava, reflections

In one of my projects I use Guava to get the class name from command line and then call appropriate constructor. User runs the .bat file with something like:

> java -jar MyClass.jar OtherClass

OtherClass is located at some package like mypackage.otherpackage. I want to call it's constructor in the code. To find the constructor, I use Guava:

```
Constructor classConstructor = null;

Set<ClassInfo> classInfos = ClassPath.from(MyClass.class.getClassLoader()).getTopLevelClassesRecursive("mypackage");
List<String> packageNames = classInfos.stream().map(classInfo -> classInfo.getPackageName()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

for (String p : packageNames) {
    try {
        classConstructor = Class.forName(p + "." + args[0]).getConstructor(String.class);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    }

    if (classConstructor != null)
                    break;
}
```

And it works just perfect on one computer but doesn't work at all on another one because `ClassPath.from(MyClass.class.getClassLoader()).getTopLevelClassesRecursive("mypackage");` returns 0 elements. I don't understand why. The code on both computers is equal, packages are equal, classes too.

Answer (score 0):

It was because of Guava version. For some reason Guava-14 that is used on the first computer works fine there, but on the second one I had to replace it with Guava-22. But after this everything worked fine.